# Only fetch Max and Min value in column - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I mention a data which i want to fetch only the max and min date values to my new table as a single row.

```
   ID   date        Comment grade
    1   12-Jul-2013 asdads  1
    1   2-Apr-2014  dfgdfg  1
    1   29-Dec-2014 ghjghj  2
    10  8-Oct-2015  cbvcvb  1
    10  10-Jan-2017 sdfsdf  5
    10  29-May-2018 ertert  4
```

I want to group by the data by ID. as
ID Date1   Date2   Comment1  comment2 Grade1 Grade2

Please help me to solve the case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us your expect result?

Comment: What's the expected result of two rows have the same min (or max) date?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The table should contain min and max date of all parameters. @jarlh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the following SQL statement with a subquery :

```
select q.* ,
       ( select comment from tab where ID = q.ID and date = q.date1 ) as comment1,
       ( select comment from tab where ID = q.ID and date = q.date2 ) as comment2,
       ( select grade from tab where ID = q.ID and date = q.date1 ) as grade1,
       ( select grade from tab where ID = q.ID and date = q.date2 ) as grade2       
  from 
  (
    select ID, min(date) as date1, max(date) as date2  
      from tab
     group by ID
   ) q  

ID  date1       date2       comment1  comment2   grade1  grade2
1   12.07.2013  29.12.2014  asdads    ghjghj        1       2
10  08.10.2015  29.05.2018  cbvcvb    ertert        1       4
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/XMHJ49314)